# Value of JavaScript variable when creating html element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery/Javascript code which creates a new button on the screen

```
$("#prefixed-list").append(`
<li class="list-group-item d-flex my-auto mx-auto border-0" order="9999999999">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info mt-3" onClick="prefixCall(urlDomain, searchContent, offset)">Load More</button>
</li>
  `);
```

urlDomain, searchContent, offset are all variables defined in the same function. Currently when the button gets created on the page

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-info mt-3" onclick="prefixCall(urlDomain, searchContent, offset)">Load More</button>`

I want it to have the value of the variables. How can that be done?

Comment: since you're already using template literal, `${urlDomain}` etc

Comment: `onclick="prefixCall('${urlDomain}', ...)"`

Comment: @JaromandaX @Barmar I have it as `onClick="prefixCall('${urlDomain}', '${searchContent}', '${offset}')"` but that did not change anything. Still showing up as the variable names in the generated HTML.

Comment: you must've done it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you're already using template literal, `${urlDomain}` etc

```js
const urlDomain="this is the urlDomain";
const searchContent = "This is searchContent";
const offset = "guess what this is";
const prefixCall = (...args) => console.log(args);
$("#prefixed-list").append(`
<li class="list-group-item d-flex my-auto mx-auto border-0" order="9999999999">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info mt-3" onClick="prefixCall('${urlDomain}', '${searchContent}', '${offset}')">Load More</button>
</li>
  `);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="prefixed-list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add event handler `on(eventname,[eventData], callback)`. This allow to listen the events from the elements you append dynamically.

You can like this:

```js
$("#prefixed-list").append(`
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex my-auto mx-auto border-0" order="9999999999">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info mt-3" id="prefixed-list-btn">Load More</button>
  </li>
`);
urlDomain="asdf", searchContent="asdf", offset="asdf"
$("#prefixed-list-btn").on("click", {urlDomain, searchContent, offset}, (ev)=>{prefixCall(ev.data.urlDomain, ev.data.searchContent, ev.data.offset)});

function prefixCall(urlDomain, searchContent, offset) {
  console.log(urlDomain, searchContent, offset);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="prefixed-list"></ul>
```

Best regards,
Bogdan Bob.